# button style on android, minimal style appears to be jagged box in emulator

Tags: android, button, themes, styles

I am working on an app for the xoom with the Honeycomb sdk. I have a basic gradient shape defined in res/drawable-hdpi/button.xml

```
... <item>        
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#848d00"
            android:startColor="#c5d401" />
    </shape>
</item> ...
```

I created a styles.xml and themes.xml which is referenced in AndroidManifest.xml to apply this style to all buttons.

For some reason when I view the buttons in the emulator they show up as unsymmetrical boxes:

http://postimage.org/image/1ozqno0uc/

Check that link to see what i'm talking about. Am I missing an attribute, is this a bug in the emulator? I applied more styles to curve the corner, but it remains divided in the middle by a pixel. I'd like it to be a regular looking box with no excess edge.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't how things look in the emulator. How does it look on a real device?

Comment: Robby, still waiting for the real device to come out. It's intended for the xoom.

Comment: I noticed the glitches go away when I take out all the LinearLayout tags i'm using. It's like it is squishing the buttons.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's normal for 3.x emulators to show misaligned lines. It's only the emulator, not on the device, so don't worry. Probably it's because of the implementation of hardware accelerated graphics.

However, it will be of great advantages for you to use a real device for 3.x and above. The emulator is painfully slow.